# PDF version 1.3 Add stamp

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I am using larval and want to add stamp on pdf documents.

My PDF files version is 1.3 and I am using FPDI package but it is not able to add PDF stamp on 1.3 version. It is working well other version. which is the best package to do this? Please suggest me

Comment: You do not say anything about the stamp. If it is an image with transparency then it is not supported in PDF 1.3

Answer (score 0):

We offer an add-on for FPDI which allows you to process PDF documents which uses compressed cross-references and streams (introduced in PDF 1.5) [here](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi-pdf-parser/details/) (not free).

Otherwise you have to remove the compressed cross-reference and streams (possible e.g. through the optimization process of Acrobat).